# Splitting GZipped PSVs as per number of rows

Tags: split, gzip

I am getting GZipped files, which contain PSV data file, that has to be dumped into my Redshift Database.

In order to optimize the Redshift Data Loads from these files, I need to split these GZipped files into multiple files based on number of Rows, without unzipping>>splitting>>zipping.

Is there a way to split the GZIP Files directly, based on the number of rows, without unzipping them?

I am getting the source files on a Unix Machine, from where i load the data to AWS S3 and then to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.  Wherever you pick to split it, the compressed data that follows that point will very likely have references to matching strings in the data that precedes that point.  There would be no escaping having to recompress.